# 'List index out of range' while reversing list

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

The problem is regarding reversing a list A of size N in groups of K. For example if `A = [1,2,3,4,5]`, `k = 3`
`Output = [3,2,1,5,4]`
The error I get, when I run this is List Index out of range on line 4.

```
def reverseInGroups(A,N,K):   
    arr1 = []
    for i in range(K):
        arr1.append(A[(N-i)%K]) #line 4
    for j in range(N-K):
        arr1.append(A[N-j-1])
    return arr1
```

Comment: no error reproduceable? `print(reverseInGroups([1,2,3,4,5],5, 3))` => `[3, 2, 1, 5, 4]`

Answer (score 1):

This will implement what you are trying to achieve:

```
def reverseInGroups(A,K):
    N = len(A)
    arr1 = []
    for i in range(0, N, K):
        arr1.extend(A[i : i+K][::-1])
    return arr1

print(reverseInGroups([1,2,3,4,5], 3))
```

Interestingly, the code in the question actually works in the example case, but it is not general.  The case where it works is where N = 2*K - 1 (although where it does not work, the elements are in the wrong order rather than an IndexError).

Answer (score 1):

Cant seem to reproduce your `'List index out of range'` error, but your logic is faulty:

> ```
> reverseInGroups(A,N,K):   
>     arr1 = []
>     for i in range(K):
>         arr1.append(A[(N-i)%K]) #line 4
>     for j in range(N-K):
>         arr1.append(A[N-j-1])
>     return arr1
> ```

```
print(reverseInGroups([1,2,3,4,5],5, 3))  # works, others get wrong result
print(reverseInGroups([1,2,3,4,5,6],6, 3))  # wrong result: [1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4]
```

prints:

```
[3, 2, 1, 5, 4] # correct
[1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4] # wrong
```

---

You fix this and make this smaller by packing it into a list comprehension:

```
def revv(L,k): 
    return [w for i in (L[s:s+k][::-1] for s in range(0,len(L),k)) for w in i]

for gr in range(2,8):
    print(gr, revv([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],gr))
```

to get:

```
2 [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9, 11]
3 [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 11, 10]
4 [4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 11, 10, 9]
5 [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 11]
6 [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7]
7 [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 11, 10, 9, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with this:

```
def reverse(l, n):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(l)-1, n):
        for item in reversed(l[i:i+n]):
            result.append(item)
    for item in reversed(l[i+n:]):
        result.append(item)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the array upto index `K` and reverse the remaining part and add these both arrays.

```
def reverseInGroups(A,N,K):
    return A[:K][::-1]+A[K:][::-1]

A = [1,2,3,4,5]
N = 5
K = 3

res = reverseInGroups(A,N,K)
print(res)
```